# cant make join 2 tabels in show function laravel

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function show($id){
 $users_services = DB::table('services')

->join('services','services.id', '=', 'users_services.service_id')
        ->get(array('users_services.id as id',
         'users_services.service_descreption as service_descreption',
        'users_services.service_link as service_link',
        'services.title as service_title','services.type as services_type'
        ))->toArray();
                                    ;   


    return  View('users_services.show')
    ->with('users_services', $users_services);
```

}

when I add the join statement I got this error and I'm sure that there are
users_services.service_id = services.id
I got this error in the view 
"

> Trying to get property 'services_title' of non-object (View: C:\new
>   xamp\htdocs\task\digisay\resources\views\users_services\show.blade.php)

"

Comment: dump the array of result and see the `services_title` is exist or not on that array.

Comment: Maybe your object doesn't have `services_title` property.

Answer (score 0):

Change the join query as follows

```
   $users_services = DB::table('services')
     ->join('users_services','services.id', '=', 'users_services.service_id')
      ->select('users_services.id as id',
     'users_services.service_descreption as service_descreption','users_services.service_link as service_link',
    'services.title as service_title','services.type as services_type'
    )
    ->get();
```